# Reading I2C data from GPS

Tags: gps, raspberry-pi, i2c

I have a ublox M8 GPS connected to my Raspberry Pi via I2C and I'm trying to pull data from it.

I'm using python to attempt to get data via the I2C connection with the GPS module but all I get back in an incrementing number each request.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

i2cdetect -y 1 returns:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- 42 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

#### Python Code

```
import smbus
import time
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address = 0x42
bus.read_byte_data(address,0x00)
bus.read_byte(address)
```

returns:

```
160
161
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am experimenting with this also.

1. Using some info from this [page](http://wiki.erazor-zone.de/wiki%3Alinux%3Apython%3Asmbus%3Adoc) about how to use the smbus.
2. And using the arduino code from [here](http://www.recoon5.ru/en/story/u-blox_EVK-7N_I2C) (note the 0xfd and 0xff bytes aren't used below)

I can get the GNGGA string below ($GNGGA means both US and Russian GPS systems are being used):

```
import time
import json
import smbus
import logging 

BUS = None
address = 0x42
gpsReadInterval = 0.1
LOG = logging.getLogger()

# GUIDE
# http://ava.upuaut.net/?p=768

GPSDAT = {
    'strType': None,
    'fixTime': None,
    'lat': None,
    'latDir': None,
    'lon': None,
    'lonDir': None,
    'fixQual': None,
    'numSat': None,
    'horDil': None,
    'alt': None,
    'altUnit': None,
    'galt': None,
    'galtUnit': None,
    'DPGS_updt': None,
    'DPGS_ID': None
}

def connectBus():
    global BUS
    BUS = smbus.SMBus(1)

def parseResponse(gpsLine):
    global lastLocation
    gpsChars = ''.join(chr(c) for c in gpsLine)
    if "*" not in gpsChars:
        return False

    gpsStr, chkSum = gpsChars.split('*')    
    gpsComponents = gpsStr.split(',')
    gpsStart = gpsComponents[0]
    if (gpsStart == "$GNGGA"):
        chkVal = 0
        for ch in gpsStr[1:]: # Remove the $
            chkVal ^= ord(ch)
        if (chkVal == int(chkSum, 16)):
            for i, k in enumerate(
                ['strType', 'fixTime', 
                'lat', 'latDir', 'lon', 'lonDir',
                'fixQual', 'numSat', 'horDil', 
                'alt', 'altUnit', 'galt', 'galtUnit',
                'DPGS_updt', 'DPGS_ID']):
                GPSDAT[k] = gpsComponents[i]
            print gpsChars
            print json.dumps(GPSDAT, indent=2)

def readGPS():
    c = None
    response = []
    try:
        while True: # Newline, or bad char.
            c = BUS.read_byte(address)
            if c == 255:
                return False
            elif c == 10:
                break
            else:
                response.append(c)
        parseResponse(response)
    except IOError:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        connectBus()
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        LOG.error(e)

connectBus()
while True:
    readGPS()
    time.sleep(gpsReadInterval)
```

Here is some of the output.

```
$GNGGA,,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*56
{
  "galt": "", 
  "DPGS_updt": "", 
  "lon": "", 
  "strType": "$GNGGA", 
  "lat": "", 
  "alt": "", 
  "fixTime": "", 
  "lonDir": "", 
  "numSat": "00", 
  "fixQual": "0", 
  "altUnit": "", 
  "galtUnit": "", 
  "horDil": "99.99", 
  "latDir": "", 
  "DPGS_ID": ""
}
```

I have it indoors away from windows, etc. So bad data expected.
Hope this helps.